# Issue using svn delete command

Tags: svn

I am trying to delete an existing tag from svn repo using the following command:

```
C:\>svn delete --username xxx --password yyy http://subversion-practice.sweng.xyz.com/cvn/repos/ps/port/tags/PORT_0310xx_05_88_tools -m Deleting PORT_0310xx_05_88_tools 2>&1
```

but it fails with the following error:

> svn: 'C:/PORT_0310xx_05_88_tools' isn't in the same repository as 'http://subversion-practice.sweng.xyz.com/cvn/repos/ps/port'

Can't figure out why it is looking for 'C:/PORT_0310xx_05_88_tools' instead of 'http://subversion-practice.sweng.xyz.com/cvn/repos/ps/port/tags/PORT_0310xx_05_88_tools'.

Answer (score 1):

For commit message with spaces you must use `-m "Deleting PORT_0310xx_05_88_tools"`, otherwise only first word will be parameter for -m, rest will be additional targets for delete

> **Each item** specified by...